# Pointy Catmull-Rom Splines

Tags: 2d, rendering, simulation, interpolation

I'm doing a 2D water simulation using springs, and interpolating between each spring-end when rendering to create a smooth water surface. The resulting water looks a little bit more like jelly. Is it possible to modify the catmull-rom to make 'pointy curves', or do I need to use a different algorithm. I just can't think of the correct search terms for what I want.

Example of what I'd like to recreate

[image: point interpolation]
<sub>(source: [vimeocdn.com](http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/217/438/217438149_640.jpg))</sub>

Instead of something like this

[image: smooth interpolation]

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You want the surface of the water to form *cusps*: points where the tangents on either side are not identical. The two endpoints of the Catmull-Rom spline control the tangent, so you can probably get some pointy waves by offsetting these higher.